# Syntax Temporary Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying o create a temporary table within a trigger but I am receiving a syntax error near "into and I don't understand why! This temporary table should save the `balance`, `ID` of participant and Wristband `ID` values from Wristband when you insert a new `WRISTBAND` with an existing `IDPARTICIPANT`. And then update the `BALANCE` of the inserted `WRISTBAND` with the values in the temporary.

CODE:

```
select w.IDPARTICIPANT, w.IDPWRISTBAND, w.BALANCE into #temp_s 
from WRISTBAND w, inserted i 
where w.IDPARTICIPANT = i.IDPARTICIPANT and w.ACTIVE = 1;

update WRISTBAND
set BALANCE = 
(
    select t.BALANCE 
    from #temp_s t 
)
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tg3_after_insert, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'." This is what it shows, when I try to run the trigger

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily see an error near the `INTO #temp_s#`, but I do see an error in your `UPDATE` query.

The `#temp_s` table in the subquery isn't correlated to the `WRISTBAND` table in any way, so you might get an error there if more than 1 row is returned (*which I assume there will be*).

```
update WRISTBAND
set BALANCE = 
(
    select t.BALANCE 
    from #temp_s t 
)
```

so, I think it would look better if it would be something like:

```
update w
set BALANCE = 
(
    select t.BALANCE 
    from #temp_s t
    where t.IDPARTICIPANT = w.IDPARTICIPANT 
)
FROM WRISTBAND w
```

Maybe this is it, since SQL sometimes behaves strangely when giving out error messages. It would be best if you posted the entire message.

Comment: Forgive this if I'm missing something as it's early for me - but - is this script reading the wristband balance and then putting it back in?

Comment: @level3looper you're right. Even if it does make no sense, it still might teach OP a lesson in correlated queries and the fact that a SELECT used to set a value in an UPDATE always needs to return 1 row. I would have put my answer in a comment, but it was too long to prove my point.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have question for you does the query always returns 1 row-

```
select w.IDPARTICIPANT, w.IDPWRISTBAND, w.BALANCE  
from WRISTBAND w, inserted i 
where w.IDPARTICIPANT = i.IDPARTICIPANT and w.ACTIVE = 1;
```

If it returns 1 row then why use temp table?

```
update WRISTBAND
set BALANCE = 
(
    w.BALANCE  
    from WRISTBAND w, inserted i 
    where w.IDPARTICIPANT = i.IDPARTICIPANT and w.ACTIVE = 1;
);
```